# I need a link that directs the user that is logged to his profile

Tags: users, links, profiles, subscription

I want a link in the form to an image in the frontpage, that direct the user that is logged to the subscription packages that are on its profile:

The link look like this:
https://mywebsite.co.uk/author/admin/?screen=acc_pay

But I want for the user part **/admin/** to change depending on the user that is logged.

I am using KingComposer:
[image]

This is the page were the link should be
[image: ![enter image description here]

And this is were it should lead undependant of the user that is logged in, so I need a customized link that leads to the author page of the user that is logged
[image]

This is the result of imputing this code
[image]

```
<?php
$author_page = is_user_logged_in() ? get_author_posts_url( get_current_user_id() ) : NULL;
$acc_pay_page = $author_page ? add_query_arg( 'screen', 'acc_pay', $author_page ) : NULL;
if ( $acc_pay_page) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $acc_pay_page ) .'"><img src="https://mywebsite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/pricing-06.png" /></a>';
} else {
    echo '<span>Please log in</span>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that KingComposer will accept PHP blocks.
This will generate a link to the current logged-in user's author page:

```
<?php
$author_page = is_user_logged_in() ? get_author_posts_url( get_current_user_id() ) : NULL;
$acc_pay_page = $author_page ? add_query_arg( 'screen', 'acc_pay', $author_page ) : NULL;
if ( $acc_pay_page) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $acc_pay_page ) .'"><img src="account_page_page.png" /></a>';
} else {
    echo '<span>Please log in</span>';
}
?>
```

Comment: How can I integrate that into an image to work as a link

Comment: Where do you want to put the code - in a template, or a shortcode, or something else? Where is the image coming from - a fixed path, or an attachement?

Comment: Is like a wordpress template on the frontpage yes, the image is in the media gallery inside wordpress, is being done in Kingcomposer.

Comment: OK, I don't know Kingcomposer sorry. The code I've written is PHP code: do you know if the raw code blocks in your image accept PHP code in `<?php` tags? I'd guess not. In which case you'd need to write a new block type or extension for Kingcomposer I'd think, and I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.

Comment: php tags are perfectly catch by the page

Comment: There seems to be something left, it doesnt direct my to https://mywebsite.co.uk/author/ANYUSER/?screen=acc_pay 
nor any other page, it doesnt act as a link

Comment: :-/ This worked for me, albeit not in Kingcomposer. OK, but you're seeing the correct image? Can you see if it does generate an `<a>` tag, without an URL then? What does get generated?

Comment: It generates the image, but it is not clickable

Comment: Oh, it's emitting actually putting the whole PHP script that I've written into the page? i.e. it's not running the PHP you've entered into the raw code block after all?